# Are future options per 100 unit?

Tags: options, futures, option-strategies, online-trading

In futures (for commodities, indices, fx...); Is 1 option for 100 future contracts ?
For example:
If I want to make a covered call option for Gold and for micro Dow jones future, How much should I buy ?
Gold : (price (1 ounce) * 100 (one contract amount) * 100 ) ?
Micro e-mini dow : (price: 34288 * 5 (micro is 5x djia I think) * 100) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a universal standard - for options on futures, typically the option contract is for *one* futures contract, which may be for a certain number of units of the underlying (e.g. 1,000 barrels of oil, or 100 troy oz of gold).

But it's not universal - you'd need to look at the [specifications of the option contract](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/gold_contractSpecs_options.html) to be certain.